# Pandas - count groupBy results

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a group of the most popular names by country using pandas. I have gotten half way as seen in the snippet but I am unclear how to convert groupedByCountry into a sorted table.

```
import math
import pandas
csv = pandas.read_csv("./name_country.csv.gz", compression="gzip")

data = csv[["name",'country']]

filtered = roleIni[data.country.notnull()]

groupedByCountry = filtered.groupby("country")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and then use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([["andy", "GB"], ["bob", "US"], ["chris", "GB"]], columns=["name", "country"])

In [12]: df.groupby("country").size().nlargest(1)
Out[12]:
country
GB    2
dtype: int64
```

It's probably more efficient however to do a direct [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on the column, and then take the [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.head.html) (`head(n)` will get the top n most popular countries):

```
In [21]: df["country"].value_counts().head(1)
Out[21]:
GB    2
Name: country, dtype: int64
```